# Display PHP code on web page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a library for PHP scripts and I want to be able to show php code on a html webpage.

I have looked at using highlight_file(); but this will show the whole page

For example, If I have a page called code.php which has an sql query on ( `select code from table where sequence = $_GET["id"]` ) - example then I use

```
Highlight_file('code.php?id=123');
```

This will work but will also show the select query which I do not want to show. I would just want to show the code from the database (code column)

How can I display just the code from the database with the correct colours and formatting etc

UPDATE:

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","charlie_library","Pathfinder0287");
mysql_select_db("charlie_library",$conn);

function highlight_code_with_id($id, $conn)
{
    $query = "select * from library_php where sequence = '$id' ";
    $rs = mysql_query($query,$conn);
    $code  = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    echo highlight_string($code["code"]);
}

// and, use it like this:
highlight_code_with_id($_GET['id'], $conn);
?>
```

I have tried the above code, which is just displaying the code in plain text

Comment: Show the whole code you have written in code.php

Answer (score 3):

use [`highlight_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) function, like this:

```
<?php
highlight_string($code);
?>
```

where `$code` is the code you have obtained from your SQL query.

---

You can create a function around this (something along the following lines):

```
<?php

function highlight_code_with_id($id, $mysqli) {
  $query = $mysqli->query("select code from table where sequence = '$id'");
  $code  = current($query->fetch_assoc());
  return highlight_string($code);
}

// and, use it like this:
echo highlight_code_with_id($_GET['id'], $mysqli);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Your code is a bit incorrect, you can use:

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","charlie_library","Pathfinder0287");
mysql_select_db("charlie_library",$conn);

function highlight_code_with_id($id)
{
    $query = "select * from library_php where sequence = '$id' ";
    $rs    = mysql_query($query);
    $code  = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);      // change is in this line
    echo highlight_string($code["code"]);
}

// and, use it like this:
highlight_code_with_id($_GET['id']);
?>
```

Note that you do not need to include `$conn` in your function, it can be ommitted. Also, note that you should use `mysqli->*` family of functions, since `mysql_*` family has been deprecated.

Comment: +1 even though `mysql_query` is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @Arjan: updated the code.. thank you for reminding me.. old habits die hard! :)

Comment: This is returning Array 1

Comment: i fixed the Array 1 issue, it now shows the code but not the way that highlight_file does (with the correct colouring etc) it just displays black text

Comment: @charlie: can you update your question to add the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

[Perhaps this would work for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291550/2748327)

This post is originally for HTML, but the answer linked above shows an example using PHP.