# HTML - Display PHP code with <?php and ?>

Tags: html, pre

I am writing a blog and when I display code, I usually do so like this:

```
< pre > < code > Code Goes Here < / code > < / pre>
```

But it will not display the starting of php `<?php` or the end `?>` and I really need it to. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: < pre > < code > Code Goes Here < / pre > < / code> this is not good. You need to close like this <1> <2> </2> </1> instead of 1 2 1 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621630/how-to-display-php-html-source-code-on-a-page

Comment: oppps I did have that way, let me fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291536/show-html-as-code?rq=1][1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display special characters in HTML, you must escape them.

```
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
& - &amp;
" - &quot;
' - &#039;
```

So in your case, you want

```
<pre><code>&lt;?php (PHP CODE HERE) ?&gt;</code></pre>
```

(Also notice the order of closing tags must match the order of opening tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;?php` and `?&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <pre><code>&lt;?php Code Goes Here ?&gt;</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how blogs work but you can try the php function "`highlight_string();`" like this:

```
<?php
highlight_string('<?php phpinfo(); ?>');
?>
```

It will output the ('input') as a string with colorcoding. 
check out its php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php